# Programa para leer y escribir archivos JSON en python

Tags: python, json, idle

tengo que hacer un programa en python que lea un archivo json y a su vez haga otro pero con datos espeficos.

Mi programa es este y archivo *Bienes.json* se encuentra en la misma carpeta que mi programa pero al correrlo parece que no es capaz de leerlo.

```
import json

def cargar_datos(ruta):
    with open(ruta) as contenido:
        resultados = json.loads(contenido)
        for resultado in resultados:
            print(resultado.get('NumeroSIAB'))

if __name__ == '__leer__':
    ruta = 'Bienes.json'
    cargar_datos(ruta)
```

> traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/jorgesmartinez/Documentos/proyecto/leer.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import json   File "/home/jorgesmartinez/Documentos/proyecto/json.py", line 4, in
>   
>       data = json.load(file) AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'
>
> > > >

Comment: Cuando importas json fíjate en el mensaje de error que te muestra que en realidad estás importando `/home/jorgesmartinez/Documentos/proyecto/json.py` Es decir, has llamado a uno de tus ficheros `json.py` y ese sustituye al módulo estándar. Renombra tu fichero.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de sintaxis, debería ser `json.loads()`

Échale un ojo a la documentación de [JSON-Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
resultados = json.loads(contenido)
```

Comment: Me sigue marcando el mismo error  AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loadS'

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te puede pasar es que tengas otro paquete llamado "json", y por tanto al realizar la importación, en vez de importarte el modulo por defecto de python, te importa otro paquete. Te dejo dos posible soluciones.

#### 1. Cambiar el nombre del modulo que está enmascarando json

Ves a la carpeta donde están tus paquetes de python y deberías tener dos json, averigua cual es el "falso" y cámbiale el nombre o elimínalo

```
import json

print(json.__file__)
```

Ejecutando ese código podrás saber cual es el módulo exacto que estás importando

#### 2. Instalar y utilizar el paquete simplejson

Si lo anterior te resulta demasiado complicado, simplemente instala el paquete `simplejson`, y podrás leer el json de la misma forma.

```
import simplejson as json

json.loads(contenido)
```